# CakePHP 3: can't remove foreign key column using MSSQL driver

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, foreign-keys, migration, phinx

I try to remove a column, which is a foreign key:

```
$table = $this->table('users');
$table->removeColumn('province_id');
$table->update();
```

Above gives DB error: `The object 'users_province_id' is dependent on column 'province_id'`. If I try to remove FK first:

```
$table = $this->table('users');
$table->removeIndex('province_id');
$table->removeColumn('province_id');
$table->update();
```

I get the same error. Using `removeIndexByName`:

```
$table = $this->table('users');
$table->removeIndexByName('users_province_id');
$table->removeColumn('province_id');
$table->update();
```

Also doesn't work. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't remove foreign key constraints, but only indexes and columns. To remove a foreign key constraint, you'd use the `dropForeignKey()` method, something along the lines of this:

```php
$table = $this->table('users');
$table
    ->dropForeignKey(
        // by columns used in the constraint, this would remove _all_
        // foreign key constraints on the table that are using the
        // `province_id` column
        'province_id',

        // optionally pass the name of the constraint in the second
        // argument instead, in order to remove only a specific single
        // constraint by its name
        'foreign_key_constraint_name'
    )
    ->removeIndex('province_id')
    ->removeColumn('province_id')
    ->update();
```

See also

- **[Phinx Cookbook > Writing Migrations > Working With Foreign Keys](https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/migrations.html#working-with-foreign-keys)**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as someone posted correct answer and than deleted it, I'll post the solution:

Instead of using `removeIndex` one should use `dropForeignKey('province_id')`.

Comment: I deleted it as it was incomplete and I had to check something first. Undeleted now with additional information on how `dropForeignKey()` works.